# EF 6 decimal gets dropped when saving to database

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-6

I'm building a SQL Server / ASP.NET Core MVC application using EF 6 that contains one model with a few decimal properties.

When I enter for example a value of 4.4 in a field and creating the entry, the corresponding property shows as 44,00 in when looking at the overview after that. Another example is a value of 12.1 will become 121,00 in the database.

I'm using the following model. The issue reproduces in all the properties using a decimal type.

```
public class Driver
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    
    public string driverName { get; set; }
    public decimal driverScore { get; set; }
    public decimal employedTime { get; set; }
    public int amtApproaches { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "No Approaches")]
    public virtual ICollection<Approach>? Approaches { get; set; }
    public int amtEvaluated { get; set; }
    public decimal lastEvaluated { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "No Evaluations")]
    public virtual ICollection<Evaluation>? Evaluations { get; set; }
    public bool isPriority { get; set; }

    public Driver()
    {
    }
}
```

I have used the following code in my `DbContext` to set the decimal precision if this is of any relevance.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Driver>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(d => d.driverScore)
                .HasColumnType("decimal(18,1)");
                entity.Property(d => d.employedTime)
                .HasColumnType("decimal(18,1)");
                entity.Property(d => d.lastEvaluated)
                .HasColumnType("decimal(18,1)");
            });
```

The entered decimal values should be stored correctly (4.4 should remain 4.4) but instead the database drops the decimal and returns a wrong value (44,00 instead of 4.4).

I'm certain this is due to a culture or browser/system settings problem. I'm from The Netherlands where we use comma (`,`) for decimal separation and dot (`.`) to indicate thousands. I want to use the US annotation using a decimal point for separation.

Comment: This has to do with transport from UI to backend. Not EF. I'm pretty sure that debugging the endpoint code will reveal that the serializer has changed the values. But to fix that we need to see all code/configuration related to this traffic.

Comment: You are right, I debugged the create `POST` action in my controller and the values in object passing the properties to the database already have all the decimal points removed. This means they are removed somewhere between the UI and the controller action. I checked the `POST` request in the browser debugger and the payload does still contain the correct formatting with decimal points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm certain this is due to a culture or browser/system settings
> problem. I'm from The Netherlands where we use comma (,) for decimal
> separation and dot (.) to indicate thousands. I want to use the US
> annotation using a decimal point for separation.

Yes, as per my investigation upon your code snippet its because of your `default-culture`. However, we can customize it as per our requirement. You could follow below steps:

**Program.cs:**

```
var defaultCulture = "en-US";
var ci = new CultureInfo(defaultCulture);
ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "."; // Defining my preferrence for number
ci.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";

// Configuring Number Seperator Using Localization middleware
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(ci),
    SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        ci,
    },
    SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        ci,
    }
});
```

**Note:** As you can see in `NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator` I am setting my preferrence for seperator. You are open to use anything you want, any kind of charaters. Please consider the order as well while placing the code in middleware. Best use would be end of your `current middleware`. As following:

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** For further reference you could check our official document below.

1. [`Custom numeric format strings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)
2. [`The "." custom specifier`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier-1)

Comment: Tried alot of different globalization options in my program.cs but this one solved the problem. Thank you!