# Using ASP.NET Core MVC with .NET 6, number from input tag in a form is losing the decimal separator when being transferred to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I was trying to create a form to add new items to my database, and my model includes a price.
The type of the price is double, and the number input on my form has a step of .01
The issue is that when submitting my new item with the form, the number is losing the decimal separator, regardless of the lang attribute of the input tag, and so using a comma or dot doesn't make a difference.
Because of this, 5.45 and 5,45 will both turn into 545.00 when written as a price on my item's list.

Here's my model:

```
public class Pizza 
{
    public Pizza(int id, string name, string description, double price, string pictureUrl) 
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        Price = price;
        PictureUrl = pictureUrl;
    }

    public Pizza() { }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Il campo è obbligatorio.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Il campo è obbligatorio.")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Il campo è obbligatorio.")]
    [Range(0, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Il prezzo non può essere negativo.")]
    public double Price { get; set; } // This is the property which is being set to the wrong value
    
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Il campo è obbligatorio.")]
    public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the code for my controller's action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult New(Pizza pizza) 
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        return View("New", pizza);
    }

    using (var db = new PizzasDbContext()) 
    {
        int modifications = db.AddPizza(pizza);
        Console.WriteLine(modifications);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a somewhat hacky solution that works for me.
The issue is that the form on my view would always, at all times, return the decimal value with a dot. This is most likely a standard of HTML or JavaScript.

The solution was to force the server's thread to use a culture that uses a dot instead of a comma to represent doubles, as the value returned from the view is actually a string, and therefore when parsed would lose any dot or useless zeroes.

The code that worked for me is the following:

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "€";
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

I found the code on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449401/20438836) StackOverflow post.

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on your code snippet, it's clear that, you have not defined the decimal precision for your `Price`  property. thus, it cannot recognize decimal point. You should update your code in following way:

**Pizza  POCO Model:**

```
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")] // OR `[Precision(18, 2)]`
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

**Note:** this means `Price` would be a decimal number which would contains upto 18 main number along with 2 decimal precision after `.` point. Keep in mind that `[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]` and `[Precision(18, 2)]` act same.  However, you can keep `public double Price` but annotation should be `[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]`

**Database Schema Should be:**

```
Price Decimal(18,2) NOT NULL
```

The above reason may causing your unexpected decimal result.

**Note:** For more details can be found in the [official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#precision-and-scale).

Comment: Just attempted this, but got the same result as before, and the number passed still resulted in a number denoted as 5.45 to be saved as 545
I applied the migration and updated my database as needed, too, so even with the correct column type, I still run into this issue. Keep in mind that when using the debugger, my object on the C# side would prematurely run into this issue, so I don't think it's an issue with the database.

Comment: Thanks for your response, if you keep `[Range(0, double.MaxValue,` it will still treted as double so please get rid of this, try with pure decimal. In addition, do you have any browser cultture configuration?

Comment: You can try with `[Range(0.0,Decimal.MaxValue), ErrorMessage = "Il prezzo non può essere negativo.")]`

Comment: A bit late, but I've found a solution and posted / marked it as such. In addition, Range only accepts doubles, no decimals or anything like that. And even if it did, had the parsing been done the same way, I doubt my issue would've been solved.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the solution you found this one of the reasons as well, furthrmore, I have asked you about your culture in comment if you could noticed. Finally, for this kind of scenario two types of solution usually provided, [`one is to specify decimal precision`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74739864/decimal-rounding-off-to-2-places-instead-of-3-in-asp-net-core-api/74740842#74740842) and another is [`setting up culture for decimal seperator`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74602101/ef-6-decimal-gets-dropped-when-saving-to-database/74609936#74609936)

Comment: Similar kind of issue I have worked on a bit ages ago which I have referred above. In addition,[`you have look here as well`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings).